# STLPort using C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stlport

I'm trying to migrate my office code from C++ to C++11 and we make heavy use of STLPorts.

There's a compiler macro (http://www.stlport.org/doc/configure.html) - _STLP_LONG_LONG, which is used in our code and works fine in C++.

However, in C++ 11, this is not defined.

```
#if defined (_STLP_LONG_LONG)
// Doesn't come here
```

How can I fix this? I tried searching on the internet but the resources are very limited.

Edit: Here's the code

```
# if defined (_STLP_MSVC) || defined (__BORLANDC__) || defined (__ICL)
# define ULL(x) x##Ui64
typedef unsigned _STLP_LONG_LONG uint64;
# elif defined (_STLP_LONG_LONG) /// <---- Here
typedef unsigned _STLP_LONG_LONG uint64;
# define ULL(x) x##ULL
# elif defined(__MRC__) || defined(__SC__)              //*TY 02/25/2000 - added support for MPW compilers
# include "uint64.h"            //*TY 03/25/2000 - added 64bit math type definition
# else
#  error "there should be some long long type on the system!"
#  define NUMERIC_NO_64 1
# endif
```

As far as I can understand, the code is trying to find a long long type for the given platform. In case of pre C++11 on linux , g++ goes to the pointed line. But when I execute g++ -std=c++11 ..., g++ skips this line and goes to error "there should be song long long type on the system!"

Comment: What C++ compiler are you now using? Given the description, a C++11-compliant compiler should not have a `long long` type, so code not entering that `#ifdef` is correct. (BTW, `#defined` is a typo, and we would need to know more about what code you are worried about the compiler skipping.)

Comment: @KenY-N I believe `long long` is standard C++11.

Comment: @zdan Sorry, lack of coffee!

Comment: If you are migrating all your platform support to C++11, you can be wild and replace the code in the edit with just `typedef unsigned long long uint64` since it is now part of the language.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that STLPorts doesn't support C++11.

If your code requires C++11, then you don't need to use `_STLP_LONG_LONG` at all, since `long long` is standard.

If your code needs to work in older C++ as well, then you can define your own macro that works with C++11 as one would expect:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    #define MY_LONG_LONG long long
#elif defined(_STLP_LONG_LONG)
    #define MY_LONG_LONG _STLP_LONG_LONG
#endif
```

Of course, if your code has to work in pre-C++11 standard, then you may also need to handle the situation where the compiler doesn't provide the `long long`-language extension i.e. use `#ifdef MY_LONG_LONG` to check whether you can use it.

EDIT: For your definition, you should probably use `std::int64_t` instead of `long long` if you need a type that is 64 bits wide, as `long long` can technically be wider than 64 bits.

Comment: `#elifdef` should be `#elif defined`, I think.